# What is the name of this plant (see pic)?

Tags: species-identification

This plant was found growing in Colombia.

[image: Foto]

Comment: @j.musser is probably a good person to ask... also consider instead asking on the gardening stack exchange

Comment: @GriffinEvo Thank you, I guess I'd agree with Luigi on *Lupinus* :)

Comment: Better suited to [gardening.se]?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That looks like a member of genus *[Lupinus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lupinus)*, flowering plants native to North and South America:

[image: Lupine]

I couldn't find a good resource for species of *Lupinus* in Columbia so I can't help you with the species, unfortunately.

Comment: Thank you! It's size confused me a little: it's much bigger compared to the ones I've seen in Europe, and it has smaller flowers.